# Where is the shopkeeper in Hengsha?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I managed to find the shopkeeper once, shortly after arriving at Hengsha, however I'm no longer able to locate him. My inventory is full, and I'd  like to sell off my extra items to clear up space.

On your first visit to Hengsha, where is the shopkeeper located?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 4 Merchants in Hengsha (3 black, 1 white market).

- LIMB Clinic
- Lin Fu Ren - Hung Hua Hotel (ground floor)
- Pen Xin Hao - Alice Pod Gardens (southwestern storage closet)

  - He later moves to the Youzhao district, in the south east (by the locker with the exploding barrels).
- Lu Pin Rong - Sewers beneath the Hengsha Port, accessible only from Harvester Hideout

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the harvester merchant is only accessible on the second visit

Comment: @yx_ You are correct, he's only available in the second visit.

Answer (score 1):

There are three, I believe. One on the Ground Floor of the Alice Garden Pods (in one of the closets), one in the basement of the Huang She Hotel (The place with the "working girls").

The third isn't as easily directed to, but it's in the same district as the Harvester Stronghold, at the end of a dead-end street.

(Based on CyberSkull's answer above, the first and third would appear to be the same).

Comment: PS: I ended the game with 40k credits. Selling stuff isn't that necessary; sometimes you can just drop stuff.

Comment: It's less about me being concerned with money, and more about being super greedy.

Comment: Shops (and credits in general) would be much more useful if all shops restocked their items or could resell what you sell them... but no... they're nothing more than places to dump credits.